# Using .files/.folders with Mono on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, configuration, mono

I'm writing a C# application on Linux, and I'd like to store the applications .config files in the user's home directory, i.e.

If the application's name is Foo.exe

```
~user/.Foo/foo.exe.config
```

instead of looking for the .config file in the same directory as the assembly.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Look into [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx).

```
string appDataDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Remember to use Path.Combine(folder1, folder2) to combine paths in order to make your app cross platform compatible.

Alternatively you could just get the environment variable `HOME`:

```
string homeDir = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME");
```

Comment: You can also get $HOME from Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) on Mac and Linux (on Windows, it's My Documents IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do:

Directory.getCurrentDirectory().

Here is it's resource:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx